# same person modified question using a different user

Tags: support, suggested-edits, multiple-accounts

In this question

[Possible small mistakes in Springer's *Linear Algebraic Groups*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608984/possible-small-mistakes-in-in-springers-linear-algebraic-groups)

the question was modified by a formally different user (probably the same person with guest login). Since the modification has additions, and since we cannot be really sure the user is the same, shouldn't the modification be rejected?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, yes. Substantial unauthorized additions to other users' posts should be reverted.

However, the two users here are clearly controlled by the same person -- they have the same gravatar. No action is necessary.

Comment: It is very easy, by the way, to have the same gravatar as someone else.

Comment: I finally got into bed. Tomorrow I will show you... :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, I see.

Comment: @PostNoBills Indeed. I have corrected it.